# When I use AsyncStorage.getItem() to retrieve the value of a specified key, it returns a Promise object as String not as an Object

Tags: react-native, promise

Stored objected is:

```
{
 name: 'Chris',
 age: 30,
 traits: {
    hair: 'brown',
    eyes: 'brown'
  },
};
```

not able to retrieve value.propertyName.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then( (value) => console.log('value ', value, 'name is ', value.name));
```

output is : **value {"name":"Chris","age":30,"traits":{"hair":"brown","eyes":"brown"}} name is undefined**.

Please let me know how to retrieve a specific value from promise object

Answer (score 12):

**AsyncStorage** saves data only as strings. You just need to use `JSON.stringify()` when saving and `JSON.parse()` when retrieving.

For instance:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key')
.then((value) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(value);
  console.log('name is ', data.name);
});
```

Another option is to use some kind of wrapper for AsyncStorage which does this for you, like: https://github.com/jasonmerino/react-native-simple-store

Answer (score 1):

You could do for set the value the following

```js
    async setAsyncStorage (key, value) {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        }
      }
```

And for get the following:

```js
    async getAsyncStorage (key) {
        try {
          const getAsyncStorageData = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
          const getAsyncStorageParsed = JSON.parse(getAsyncStorageData);
          return getAsyncStorageParsed;
        } catch (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fore GetItem:
const data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('DataEnable'));
this.setState({dataenable_user:data})

For SetItem:
await asyncStorage.setItem('DataEnable',JSON.stringify(this.state.dataenable_user));